# trying to understand some codes in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

project/index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . './library'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . './application/models/'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
include "Zend/Loader.php";
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Controller_Front');
// setup controller
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->throwExceptions(true);
$frontController->setControllerDirectory('./application/controllers');
// run!
$frontController->dispatch();
?>
```

Zend/Controller/Front.php

```
<?php
...
class Zend_Controller_Front
{
...
    protected static $_instance = null;
...
    protected $_throwExceptions = false;
...
    protected function __construct()
        {
            $this->_plugins = new Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker();
        }
...
    public static function getInstance()
        {
            if (null === self::$_instance) {
                    self::$_instance = new self();
            }

        return self::$_instance;
        }
...
    public function throwExceptions($flag = null)
        {
            if ($flag !== null) {
                    $this->_throwExceptions = (bool) $flag;
                    return $this;
            }

            return $this->_throwExceptions;
        }
...
}
...
?>
```

Questions:

1. `$this->_plugins = new Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker();` 
   what is the usage of this class:`Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker`? it seems it does not do anyhing in project/index.php
2. `public function throwExceptions($flag = null)` 
   why  `$flag !== null, return $this;` while `$flag == null, return $this->_throwExceptions;`? why not both return $this?
3. `$frontController->setControllerDirectory('./application/controllers');` "." means the current directory? why do we need to have "."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the usage of this class:Zend_Controller_Plugin_Broker?

It is for managing controller plugins. If you call `$front->registerPlugin()` the plugin broker is what handles the call. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html for more info.

> why $flag !== null, return $this; while $flag == null, return $this->_throwExceptions;?

It allows the function serve two purposes. If you call it with no parameters, the current value of throwExceptions is returned. If you call it with a parameter you are setting the value.

> $frontController->setControllerDirectory('./application/controllers'); "." means the current directory? why do we need to have "."?

Why not? It makes it clearer that the path is relative to the current directory.